# Calling SQL database and processing unit from NT services

Tags: architecture, windows-services, service, nt

I need to process files whenit get dropped to folder and update details in the DB.

I have an NT service written which detects the file drops

Questions hovering my mind:

1- Should I use this same NT service to process it?

2- Is NT service thread safe by defualt in nature?

3- Should I process files within NT service or is there a better way to processing files, like handing over files to different program..

4- Does it make sense for NT service to connect to DB? (I am not sure if DB and NT service logic would reside in the same machinein future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we have had a similar situation, we have done it as follows:

- First service, picks up the file validates its contents and imports the data into staging tables.
- Second process takes the information from the staging tables and sends it into the system.

This is similar to the ETL - Extract Transform Load, used for dataware houses.